# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.security.AccessController.doPriviledged

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I have this following codes which throws an error:

```
if(download_started){
    if(initDownload.isRunning()) initDownload.cancel();
    if(checkStatus.isRunning()) checkStatus.cancel();
    if(processDownload.isRunning()) processDownload.cancel();
}
```

`initDownload`,`checkStutus`,`processDownload` is an implementation of `javafx.concurrent.Task`, but evertime I call the `cancel` method, it throws an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.security.AccessController.doPriviledged
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.cancel(Task.java:1009)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.cancel(Task.java:997)
    at com.example.page.Download$5.handle(Download.java:156)
    at com.example.page.Download$5.handle(Download.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:59)
```

**By the way, this is a Javafx application deployed in Android. How to resolve this?**

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.rameses.Main'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'lib/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        packagingOptions {
        exclude 'build.properties'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {    
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.0';
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-desktop:2.0.0';
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-android:2.0.0';
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-ios:2.0.0';
}
```

Task Implementation:

```
public class InitDownloadTask extends Task<String> {

    private Map params;
    private MobileDownloadService mobileSvc;

    public InitDownloadTask(Map params){
        this.params = params;
        mobileSvc = new MobileDownloadService();
    }

    @Override
    protected String call() throws Exception {
        String batchid = mobileSvc.initForDownload( params );
        return batchid;
    }

}
```

Comment: From the exception I get that the `AccessController` found on your classpath does not have the method `doPriviledged`. So there could be an incosistency in the vm version and the javafx backport or you have could maybe configure a special security manager.

Comment: Try updating the version of the plugin to 1.0.8. Several Java 8 missing classes where added recently. Charm version now is 2.2.0.